# Issue with AudioKit v5 oscillator frequency ramp

Tags: audiokit

I'm new to AudioKit and am using v5. The oscillator frequency ramp doesn't seem to work as expected. The following example has 2 successive ramps. First it ramps 440-880, but then sounds like it goes 880-660 instead of 440-660.

If I comment out `osc.$frequency.ramp(to: 660.0, duration: 1.0)`, it ramps 440-880, then ramps extremely quickly to 440 but gets there.

Seems like something isn't resetting after the ramp.

(The `sleep`s are only for testing.)

Is this a bug? Is there something else I should be doing? Any insight would be much appreciated! Thanks!

```
import Cocoa
import AudioKit

class Test {

    let akEngine = AudioEngine()
    let osc = Oscillator()

    func setup() {
        osc.amplitude = 0.1
        akEngine.output = osc
        do {
            try akEngine.start()
        } catch {
            print("Couldn't start AudioEngine.")
        }
        osc.frequency = 440.0
        osc.start()
        osc.$frequency.ramp(to: 880.0, duration: 1.0)
        sleep(2)
        osc.stop()
        sleep(1)
        osc.frequency = 440.0
        osc.start()
        osc.$frequency.ramp(to: 660.0, duration: 1.0)
        sleep(2)
        osc.stop()
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This probably deserves an explanation, or maybe it should be fixed to work as you have it above, but once you start automating changes, you should stick with the automation syntax and not jump out to plain setting of values. For you this means just replacing `osc.frequency = 440` with `osc.$frequency.ramp(to: 440.0, duration: 0.0)` and I believe you will get the effect you want.

Comment: Ah, ok. Got it. Thanks! And is that on a per-parameter basis -- if I automate frequency, I can still set amplitude directly?

Comment: After more testing, parameters do seem independent. But, one more thing I just noticed: if I set an oscillator amplitude at 0 directly and increase directly, there's an initial attack which is more than 0 then it's soft (like a musical accent) and goes up. If I set it at 0 by ramping with 0 duration, there's no initial accent, starts soft, and I can increase it directly still (although maybe that's unintentional given what you said).

Comment: Yes, ramping is per parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Setting a parameter (`osc.frequency = 440.0`) causes a tiny ramp to be used to avoid zippering (equivalent to `osc.$frequency.ramp(to: 440.0, duration:epsilon)`). The test code immediately applies another ramp, overriding the zippering ramp.

If you insert a `sleep` after your second `osc.start()`, you'll hear the quick zipper ramp back to 440.

Comment: I see (hear). Good to know! Thanks!