# How to ramp PlaygroundOscillator to value with AudioKit in Swift?

Tags: swift, audiokit

Is there a way to change the value (frequency, volume etc.) of an PlaygroundOscillator over time in AudioKit?

I have this code and would like to ramp the volume to 0 at the end, so that there is no click sound when the oscillator is stopped.

```
var audioEngine = AudioEngine()
var osc = PlaygroundOscillator()                        
audioEngine.output = osc
do {
    try audioEngine.start()
} catch {
    print("could not start audio engine")
}
osc.play()
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
    osc.stop()
}
```

I would like to do the same as in this question, but I couldn't find the Oscillator() class anymore, so I'm assuming it is deprecated.

[Issue with AudioKit v5 oscillator frequency ramp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67202171/issue-with-audiokit-v5-oscillator-frequency-ramp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the playground oscillator's parameters are not able to be ramped. It is a simple generator for playgrounds and tests. For anything more serious, you should use something like SoundpipeAudioKit on top of AudioKit.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Somehow I can't figure out how to use that package correctly. Is there some tutorial on how to use the different AudioKit packages?

Comment: @wall-e It's pretty straightforward, keep at it.

Comment: My mistake was that I forgot to add the package under 'General' -> 'Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content' , if anyone does the same mistake as me :)